# DataBind versus setting control properties

Tags: asp.net, html, data-binding

Regarding these two approaches:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><%# DateTime.Now %></asp:Label>
```

and

```
Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Which do you use and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are the same.

Personally, I prefer the programmatic approach (number 2) because code-behind more engineered and easier to maintain. Well, this is a simple case where you write the current time, of course, but, in general, it's better to leave markup for graphics layout and use code as much as possible. In other complex scenario, you will find easier to refactor the code or analyse it with profilers.

Hope to have been of help. Remember, it's all IMHO :)

Comment: Number 2 is easier to debug I find.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer depends upon if your control is in a databound list.  If so then it would be advantageous to use the data binding syntax of the first example, simply because it is more direct, and you don't have to handle the ondatabound event for each item, and lookup the controls with find control, so it is easier to implement, less code, less complex, and easier to maintain in that sense.

But if you are just loading  normal contorls not in a repeating list then the second method is best because you don't have to go though the extra step of databinding to show your value, and you can keep all your code to bind the control values together.  This is just my opinion though.